# Sony camera Api for usb communication(a5000)

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Dose the Sony Camera SDK support the PC control via USB communication?
My Sony Camera model is a5000.

I want to develop PC application for Sony camera control via USB.
My development environment is C++ and Windows 7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Sony Camera API only supports communication through direct Wifi connection to the camera's hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still looking into this for myself, but it does have some aspects of PTP control through USB. The proprietary api mentioned in another answer is WiFi. I found vague comments that the PTP protocol isn't Sony's main thrust, however, so I'm concerned it might be a bit limited.

Comment: Please let us know if you find anything! It would be amazing if I could use USB instead of WiFi, since I find the transfer speeds with WiFi to be very inconsistent.

Comment: I found a Linux application called Entangle, but while it can take a still image from my A6000 over USB, it doesn't work with the video capabilities of the camera. So, my guess is the PTP implementation is limited in that respect too (as Entangle seems like it can handle other cameras' video stuff). All very disappointing.

Comment: Well that's better than nothing. Thanks! I'll look into it.